# Does signed request contain page param when user has NOT authorized the app?

Tags: facebook, tabs

In a Page Tab App:

Does signed request contain the 'page' param when user has NOT authorized the app?

Need to make sure I can get the page id I am showing on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.  What will be missing is the user id.